# Laravel custom Request Validation for CameCase model

Tags: laravel

In custom GroupRequest in rules() I can get id of Group (that's the Model name) by $this->group->id.

```
public function rules()
{
    if ($this->method() == 'PATCH') {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|min:2|max:255|unique:groups,name,'.$this->group->id,
        ];
    } else {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|min:2|max:255|unique:groups',
        ];
    }
}
```

How can I do it in custom ArticleCategoryRequest... in rules() but id of ArticleCategory (that's the Model name)...

$this->articlecategory->id don't work.

Comment: gotta love that cameCase

Comment: the name is the route parameter you defined. also what "doesn't work"?

Comment: @derek camelCase ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the route variable you used.

If you declared your route like this :

```
Route::patch('article-categories/{articleCategory}', 'ArticleCategoryController@update');
```

You should be able to use `$this->articleCategory` in your `ArticleCategoryRequest`. And if there is implicit model binding you should be able to get the `$this->articleCategory->id`.

Comment: And that was the key. I think that this variable is defined based on model name or something. In route I used just $category. All works now. Thanks for help.